# How can I test locally AWS Glue Jobs using aws-glue-libs Docker images?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

At the moment I am testing my Glue Pyspark Jobs using a Docker image based on `python:3.8` with some extra libraries installed (included PySpark), `localstack:localstack` (to mock S3/Cloudwatch mostly) and `postgres:9` to emulate Redshift. This is very slow and heavy environment to run locally and for this reason I have been looking at other alternatives like `amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_2.0.0_image_01` as suggested in this article: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/develop-and-test-aws-glue-version-3-0-jobs-locally-using-a-docker-container/ for local testing. Despite of what is said in the article tho I cannot find a concrete advantage respect to my current solution but maybe I am missing something. Is there a way with that to replace `localstack` and `postgres` using that images?